# Remove items from Array List stored in shared preferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist, gson, typetoken

I have a shopping cart where I want to delete a product but I'm facing an issue.
I can add the product and store it in shared preferences, but when it comes to delete nothing happens. Here is my code in adapter:

```
holder.removeProduct.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(ITEMS_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = preferences.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = preferences.getString("artikujtShporta", "");
            ArrayList<Artikujt> artikullObject = gson
                    .fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Artikujt>>(){}.getType());

            if (artikullObject != null) {
                artikullObject.remove(artikulli);
                String jsonString = gson.toJson(artikullObject);
                mEditor.putString("artikujtShporta", jsonString);
                mEditor.apply();
            }
        });
```

The same code I used to add product, with arraylist.add(). What I'm doing wrong here, can someone help.

edit:

```
holder.addItems.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //listener.setCounter(0);
            SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(ITEMS_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = preferences.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = preferences.getString("artikujtShporta", "");
            ArrayList<Artikujt> artikullObject = gson
                    .fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Artikujt>>(){}.getType());

            if (artikullObject != null) {
                artikullObject.add(mArtikull);
                String jsonString = gson.toJson(artikullObject);
                mEditor.putString("artikujtShporta", jsonString);
                mEditor.apply();
            } else {
                ArrayList<Artikujt> arrayArtikuj = new ArrayList<>();
                arrayArtikuj.add(mArtikull);
                Type listOfTestObject = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Artikujt>>(){}.getType();
                String s = gson.toJson(arrayArtikuj, listOfTestObject);
                mEditor.putString("artikujtShporta", s);
                mEditor.apply();
            }

        });
```

Comment: Can you also add the code for the Artikujt class? You probably didn't implement the equals method correctly

Comment: @Flood2d editet my question

Comment: Yes but the add procedure is not relevant in this issue. The Artikujt class code is necessary to debug it properly. Post the code of Artikujt class

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong way of removing the object

```
 artikullObject.remove(artikulli);
```

The above method will remove the same object from the list, but as you parsed the list from Gson, a new List will is prepared, and all the objects will have a different object.

How you can remove this object?

If you have any unique id of the object, get its index by iterating the loop, then remove the object with this index in the list.

for Example, your Artikujt class is like this

```
class Artikujt{
String uId;
// other data members..
}
```

// Loop your list, check the index of the item to remove

```
holder.removeProduct.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(ITEMS_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = preferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = preferences.getString("artikujtShporta", "");
        ArrayList<Artikujt> artikullObject = gson
                .fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Artikujt>>(){}.getType());

        if (artikullObject != null) {
        int indexToRemove = -1
         for(int i=0 ; i<artikullObject.size(); i++){
           if(artikullObject.get(i).uid.equals(artikulli.uid)){
            indexToRemove = i;
            break;
           }
          }
      if(i!=-1){
        artikullObject.remove(indexToRemove);
       }

            String jsonString = gson.toJson(artikullObject);
            mEditor.putString("artikujtShporta", jsonString);
            mEditor.apply();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This will work but it is not the good way to do it. The good way is to override the equals method in the Artikujt class to handle the equality test. The list remove will do the rest

Comment: yeah, but again, he will have to override the hashcode method for that, to cope with the java contract, because If he is using this data class in any hash-based data structure, or might use in future, that might cause some issue. Depends a lot on user's requirement.

Comment: Every collection use the equals and hashcode. Reimplementing the mechanic of removing/inserting objects is not the proper way. It is effortless to override equals and hashcode methods and it should became a habit as soon as possible. Now imagine if he want to use a Set, he have to check if the set already contains the object manually which completely cancels the purpose of the Set class.

Comment: make sure the id you are using is correct, unique id

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't override the `equals(Object)` method in your `Artikujt` class. To follow the contract you also need to override the `hashCode` method.
If you can provide an id to identify your objects you can implement it like this

```
public class Artikujt {
    private int id;

    //Other stuff

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Artikujt artikujt = (Artikujt) o;
        return id == artikujt.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Integer.hashCode(id);
    }
}
```

This is because the List `remove` method will call the `equals` method on each object contained in the list and remove it when it returns true. When you deserialize the list from the json you are creating completely different instances of the `Artikujt` class that are compared using `==` in your case which is wrong.

If you are using an IDE like IntelliJ or Android Studio it is very easy to override these methods. You just need to select the fields you want to include in the equality check and the IDE will generate the `equals` and `hashcode` automatically

Comment: If you are using it, then make sure to not use this data class in any hashing based data structure or If you use, override the hashcode() method properly to prevent further issues

Comment: in the return id = artikujt.id needs to return a boolean

Comment: It is an == so it will result in a boolean expression. id == artikujt.id ? true : false; is redundant